# Divide list in 2?

Tags: python, list

As a result of my analysis, I will have a list where every measurement will occur twice. There might be double measurements (1 is measured twice in this case)

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

My desired outcome:

```
outcome = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Order does not matter, as long as every measurement only occurs once.

Since there might be double measurements, I cannot use `unique()`.

Is there a way to efficiently half the list so every measurement only occurs once?

Edit for clarification: The list elements from double measurements will occur 4 (in this case) or more times, the ones from repeated measurements will occur twice

Comment: `set` is your friend...

Comment: What logic is being applied here?

Comment: why is 1 repeated in your desired output? shouldn't the desired output be (1,2,3,4)? Otherwise, could you explain the logic to obtain the output?

Comment: I have 5 measurements, and 2 of them are measured to be 1.

Comment: so how we distinguish which numbers are from repetitions and which from repeated measurements? It's unclear how you obtain the desired output

Comment: The ones from repeated measurements will occur 4 (in this case) or more times, the ones from repeated measurements will occur twice

Comment: Isn't this last comment an essential part of the logic that should be in the question? So basically if a number appears twice times it should be 1 time in the result, and numbers that appear 4 ties should appear twice in the output?

Comment: That last paragraph (and comment) now mentions "repeated measurements" twice. The two parts of the sentence contradict each other. I suppose you intended to place a "not" somewhere or something.

Comment: Elerium115 and trincot, thank you for the comments, I changed this in the original post

Comment: What is `unique()`? Are you using some extra library? Which we could also use?

Comment: So you want the first `n` elements of a list containing `2*n` elements, or could the first measurement of a pair occur after the second measurement of some other pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no logic as to where the elements are in the list that need to be discarded, then one option is to use `Counter`, and halve the counts:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(example_list)
for key in c:
    c[key] //= 2
lst = list(c.elements())
```

For your example input, `lst` will be `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 4):

If you sort the `example_list`, you can pick every 2nd element for your new list:

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]
outcome = sorted(example_list)[::2]
```